# my tkinter window ceases working when clicking child window's icon

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="timer = 0")
label.pack()
nowTime=0

def nextTime():
    global root,label,nowTime
    label.config(text=nowTime)
    
    nowTime+=1
    root.after(1000, nextTime)
    
nextTime()

# child window
child = tk.Toplevel()

tk.mainloop()
```

i made a smoll app which generates window with label, and it increases its time
and it generates child toplevel window

when i click the "child toplevel windows icon", the main app which increases the time text ceases working, how can i fix this?

i used "grab_set()" method, but it disable all the event including "close window"
so i think it's not a fundamental solution, can i solve that without disabling all events?

Comment: It worked for me. Comment out this `#child = tk.Toplevel()`. So you don't  need it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the icon of one of the toplevel windows you get a system menu dropped down (at least on Windows). While this menu is being shown it seems to be running it's own event loop and the the normal Tk events are not being processed. With the counter design this means a pause in your counter. You could change this to display the elapsed number of seconds if that is what you are counting so that once the menu is dismissed your display catches up.

Alternatively, in testing this it looks like as long as your dialog toplevel has a menu itself then the Tk events are processed normally and the counter will continue.